# MYSQL/PHP error of xampp on windown server

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp

for some reason my mysql lost connection and xampp didn't restart resulting in my website getting the following error:

> Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Normally, you can use
> only one of the protocol, network address, or port for each socket
> address.
>
> Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] The socket operation
> could not be performed because the system buffer space is insufficient
> or the queue is full.

Can someone help me explain what is causing this error? and what is the solution to it? Look forward to the help ! Thank you so much

I have updated windows before

Comment: This is related to the server specification, like how much is the RAM and CPU that is used, can you please tell us if this is locally happening or on live server?